# Subtracting fixed point binary numbers?

Tags: fixed-point

ello guys,

I know this is really silly but I am a little confused about how to do the following operation by hand:

0.25-0.5? or any similar questions

Also, when it comes to fixed point signed numbers, how do you subtract them?

Say I choose my MSB to be the sign and the 7th bit in an 8 bit number to be 1, while bits 6-0 are the fractional part as shown below:

[SIGN][2^0][2^-1][2^-2][2^-3][2^-4][2^-5][2^-6]

So for example: 01.100000 is 1.5 in decimal.

When aligning the decimal point its easy to add say 1+0.25:

01.000000
+00.010000
=01.010000 = 1.25 in decimal

But how would I do 0.25-1? or -0.25-1?

Hope you can help!

Comment: why do you ask 2 questions about fixed-point arithmetics? Why don't just combine it in 1?

Answer (score 3):

Using a sign-magnitude representation, like you've done here, will complicate matters greatly (and will saddle you with a bit pattern which represents "negative zero", separate from the all-zero "normal zero"). It's certainly a workable representation, but, as you're discovering, it's considerably more complicated to work with.

Using a two's complement representation, where the highest bit represents a negative value of twice the magnitude of the next highest bit (in this case, -2^1) will simplify matters immensely, as it will allow you to perform addition and subtraction exactly as if both numbers were unsigned. With such a representation, for instance:

```
 0.25 = 00 010000
-1.00 = 11 000000
      -----------
        11 010000 = -0.75
```

and

```
-0.25 = 11 110000
-1.00 = 11 000000
      -----------
        10 110000 = -1.25
```

To convert from the sign-magnitude representation to two's complement:

- If the number is positive, leave it alone.
- If the number is negative, invert every bit other than the sign bit and add 1 (using unsigned addition).

For instance, to convert from your sign-magnitude representation of -0.75 to two's complement:

```
Sign/magnitude: 10 110000
        Invert: 11 001111
            +1: 11 010000 -> two's complement
```

To convert in the opposite direction, reverse the process (subtract 1, then invert).

Comment: Hmm...well I am doing this for an assignment we have been set at university so I have to work with the sign bit as shown above.

But now I am a little confused. How is 11 010000 = -0.75? shouldn't it be -1.25? and 10 110000 = -0.75?

Comment: Could I potentially just take the number in the signed bit form first. Then remove the sign by setting it to 0 and then doing two's compliment to change the number? i.e:

-0.25 = 10 010000 

Remove the sign 

0.25 = 00 010000

Do two's compliment:

-0.25 is now:

11110000

Comment: `11.010000` = -2 + 1 + 0.25 = -0.75. `10.110000` = -2 + 0.5 + 0.25 = -1.25.

Comment: Sorry!! Still confused lol

the MSB represents the sign right? so:

11.010000

- 2^0 + 2^(-2) = -1.25
if I assume the MSB is NOT the sign bit then:

2^1+2^0 + 2^-2 = 0.75 (where do you get the '-' from?)

There is also the additional problem that in my assignment I only have 16 bits where bit 16 is the sign bit and bit 15 = 2^0 = 1. The 13 other bits represent the fraction as shown below:

[SIGN]{2^0]{2^-1]{2^-2]...{2^-14] using this format how would I do say 0.25-1 etc?

Comment: ahh.. I sorta figured out what you added above too (took em a loong time of playinga round with the numbers..). So after I get the two's compliment representation I could just add it to the positive number and it should work out?

To do: 1-0.75:
`01 000000
+11 010000
---------
00 010000`

Comment: ok, I see that 1-0.75 works as shown in my comment. but how about 0.75-1?

Comment: ah hold on, so in the 0.75-1 case:

`0.75 = 00110000`
`-1   = 11000000`
`     = 11110000`

Now inverting back since there is a negative sign

`-0.25 = 10010000`

Yeah?